# Error creating login using C#

Tags: c#, connection-string

I am having trouble getting my login to work and would like some expertise, below is the coding from Visual Studio:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace CO6009DissertationV5
{
    public partial class frmLogin : Form
    {
        public frmLogin()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=SQL2016.FSE.Network;Initial Catalog=db_1430715_co6009_dissertation;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=user_db_1430715_co6009_dissertation");
            **cn.Open();**
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from tbl_users where username = '" + txtUsername.Text + "', and password = '" + txtPassword.Text + "' ", cn);
            SqlDataReader dr;
            dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            int count = 0;

            while (dr.Read())
            {
                count += 1;
            }

            if (count == 1)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("OK");
                frmWelcome1 formDefault = new frmWelcome1();
                formDefault.Show();
            }

            else if (count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Duplicate username amd password");
            }

            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Username or password is not correct");
            }

            txtUsername.Clear();
            txtPassword.Clear();

            ///this.Hide();
            //frmWelcome1 formDefault = new frmWelcome1();
            //formDefault.Show();
        }

        private void btnExit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Database from SQL Management Studio:

```
CREATE table tbl_users
(
    userid int PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY,
    username varchar(50) NULL,
    password varchar(50) NULL,
    role varchar (50) NULL,
)
```

More Detail

> {"A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)"}

When I try to run the code and enter the username and password, it gives me an error at **cn.Open()**, saying sqlException was unhandled.

Please help.

Comment: please have a look at [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: do you have password info in connection string?

Comment: This is the error I got:

Answer (score 1):

probably your connection String is wrong try to change and insure you are using a correct Username, password & Data Source. if those data are correct maybe your SQL service is not running.

Answer (score 0):

I think your SQL Server service is in stop state. Go to windows services and put it on running state.

Answer (score 0):

There are several points you should check.

1. Check if db instance is up & running
2. Check if your db is configured for remote access
3. Check if your connection string is correctly set

In addition your code is prone to security leaks such as sql injection etc. You should also point out those isses for production purposes.